# w3c markup validation error for a form

Tags: html, validation

[w3c markup validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) for a `form`

I have a sphider search `form` that works perfectly well but it doesn't validate and I get the following error:-

Attribute `action` not allowed on element `input` at this point.

From line 62, column 7; to line 62, column 155

```
t">↩

 <input type="text" name="query" id="query" value=""action="include/js_suggest/suggest.php" method="get" columns="2" autocomplete="off" delay="1500"><input
```

Is there a way to still implement the suggestions and get it to validate?

This is the code for the form:-

```
<header id="header">
<div class="row uniform 50%">
<!-- Search -->
    <div class="2u$ 12u$(xsmall)" id="search_form">
        <form action="../sphider/search.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="query" id="query" value="" action="include/js_suggest/suggest.php" columns="2" autocomplete="off" delay="1500"><input class="button small" type="submit" value="Search">
            <input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../sphider/search.php?adv=1" class="searchtxt">Advanced search</a></form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure what you want the `action` attribute to do, but is not valid for an `input` tag.  `action` is only valid for the [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) tag.  You can find the list of valid `input` attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Thanks but that isn't very helpful, I know it's not valid, that's exactly the reason why I made the post. I am looking for a workaround that will validate.

This is for a database driven search, if you were to search for "white" and typed as far as whit it would come up with a list of words that have already been searched. i.e.

whit
white
white pages
white house


These are stored in the database and accessed by suggest.php which this element calls to include, in order to display the list. 

This works perfectly well in all browsers but I would of course prefer that all of the code validates.

Comment: @Rebel , what does the `include/js_suggest/suggest.php` code do?